# Couch db list returns only [object Object][object Object]

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have a functioning view that I'm trying to output in a specially formatted way. 
But I can't get the list function to work properly.

The only return i get is [object Object][object Object]

The ammount of [object Object] is the same number as documents returned by the view.

It might be my lack of skill in Javascript that is the problem. How should I do to get the string content of row.value?

This is the list function:

```
 "foo": "function(head, req) {
      var row; 
      while(row = getRow()) { 
           if (row.value!=null){
                send(row.value);} 
           else {send(\"fail\")}
      }
 }"
```

Edit: This is the [way the couch db wiki suggests](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later) you should handle this.
 Which is almost identical to my implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple problem. The function didn't seem to serialize the objects, which was couch db documents. 
I have to specify which attribute to access.

```
"foo": "function(head, req) {
      var row; 
      while(row = getRow()) { 
           if (row.value.symbol!=null){
                send(row.value.symbol);} 
           else {send(\"fail\")}
      }
 }"
```

The addition of the attribute, in this case symbol, solved. it.

Comment: wonderful, I like using stackoverflow as a notepad for issues you found a solution to ! :)

Comment: Well @DanieleB, I really hate when you search for an answer and realize someone a long time ago asked the same question at a random forum and probably found an answer by themselves and then didn't share their knowledge. So I try to not be so egoistic and share solutions to my problems where other people often manage to help me. :)